# Single sign-on between two UAG servers

Tags: reverse-proxy, single-sign-on, microsoft-forefront-2010

The situation:

site1.company.com is published in UAG 1 (Datacenter 1)
site2.company.com is published in UAG 2 (Datacenter 2)

My question:

Is it at all possible to set up a single sign on between the two UAG servers? Authentication information in the HTTP-Request created on UAG1 should be accepted on UAG2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found all the information I needed here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee921441.aspx